# Crear un nuevo array a base de otro array, pero sin los datos repetidos

Tags: java, array

Como dice el titulo, estoy tratando de crear un segundo array a base de un array original, pero emitiendo los valores que se encuentran repetidos.

Mi problema es que el código no funciona como lo esperaría, puesto que haga lo que haga no consigo que genere el nuevo array sin los repetidos satisfactoriamente.

Agradezco de antemano.

Código:

```
String[] ape = new String[]{"Acevedo","Uribe","Osorio","Uribe","Acevedo","Correa","Milan"};
String[] nuevosApellidos= new String[ape.length];
    String temp="";
    int c=0;
    for(int k=0;k<e;k++){
        nuevosApellidos[c]= ape[k];
        temp= nuevosApellidos[c];
        List<String> iterador = Arrays.asList(nuevosApellidos);
        if(k>1){
            if(iterador.contains(temp)){
                System.out.println("El apellido "+temp+" ya estaba en el arreglo");
                if((k+1)<nuevosApellidos.length)nuevosApellidos[c]= ape[k+1];
                nuevosApellidos[c]="Vacío";
            }
        }
        c++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la logica de tu implementación, llama la atencion un par de cosas:

- Siempre asignas el valor de un apellido al nuevo arreglo, a pesar de que *podria* estar repetido: `nuevosApellidos[c]= ape[k]`
- Solo verificas si tienes repetidos para `k > 1` por lo que podrias tener `k=0` y `k=1` repetido.
- Da lo mismo si el siguiente if se cumple o no, siempre lo sobreescribes en la siguiente linea.

  ```
  if((k+1)<nuevosApellidos.length)nuevosApellidos[c]= ape[k+1];
  nuevosApellidos[c]="Vacío"
  ```

En lugar de eso:

- Solo deberias asignar al nuevo arreglo si es que no esta repetido
- Si esta repetido, podrias asignar `"Vacío"` o simplemente no aumentar el contador `c`

  ```
  for (int k = 0; k < e; k++) {
      temp = ape[k];
      List<String> iterador = Arrays.asList(nuevosApellidos);
      if (iterador.contains(temp)) {
          System.out.println("El apellido " + temp + " ya estaba en el arreglo");
          nuevosApellidos[c] = "Vacío";
      } else {
          nuevosApellidos[c] = temp;
      }
      c++;
  }
  ```

Comment: Eureka! Veo que era un error un poco... tonto. Muchas gracias por ayudarme con este error de lógica.